# Where can I host a csv so I can directly read it into a neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j

I have a csv and I want to read it directly into a Neo4J database. I'm envisioning something along the lines of:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///somewhere_accessable_to_anyone/some_csv.csv' line AS
```

I tried the public folder in my Dropbox but that just gives a link to the csv.

I've tried some file hosting sites and again, they just want to host the file with a link that is accessible to click on for download, and displayed on an ad-packed page.

Has anyone found a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Google spreadsheets: http://blog.bruggen.com/2014/07/using-loadcsv-to-import-data-from.html

From that blog written by [Rik](https://www.blogger.com/profile/03690347549685761941), here are the main take away's:

1. the spreadsheet needs to be publicly accessible over the internet.
2. you need to generate the download URI of the CSV export
3. Import process in Neo4j is very simple now, with Load CSV

```
  load csv with headers from "your url to spreadsheet"
  as csv
  fieldterminator ','
  merge (col:COLOUR { name: csv.Colour})
  with col,csv
  match (n:COLOUR {name: col.name})
  create (p:PERSON {name: csv.Name})-[:HAS]->(col);
```

Comment: I've moved the text from the blog to this answer so your answer isn't barely more than just a link. If the blog goes away, we still have the most relevant parts here.

Answer (score 6):

As for a Google Drive approach, you don't even need to first open the CSV file in Sheets. Simply click the CSV to view it

[image]

Take note of the `FILE_ID` (highlighted in blue above) and add it the URL below as follows

`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID`

This url is a direct link to the file download which tools like `Neo4j` or `pandas.read_csv()` can use.

Answer (score 2):

After searching for hours, I finally found the solution that worked.

The best option is through Google Spreadsheet

1. Host the file on Google drive
2. Navigate to the file and open in Google Sheets
3. Click on File > Share > Share with others > Change to anyone with the link > Done
4. In the address bar, you will notice a link like this
   `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T0OygJBMcStdC7dTP0CKofEr3dCTsMcRJho/`
5. Just copy the part after 'd' which is `1T0OygJBMcStdC7dTP0CKofEr3dCTsMcRJho` in our case.
6. Now, plug in the key we copied above in  `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{copied_key_here}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv`
7. Hence, in our case, the link will be `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T0OygJBMcStdC7dTP0CKofEr3dCTsMcRJho/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv`

We now have the link ready

Open Neo4j Aura Console and click Neo4j Browser and connect with your credentials
[image]

Next run the following query to test

`LOAD CSV FROM 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T0OygJBMcStdC7dTP0CKofEr3dCTsMcRJho/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv' AS ROW RETURN ROW LIMIT 10`

[image]

Credits: [Using Google Sheets to Host Editable CSV Files](https://www.megalytic.com/knowledge/using-google-sheets-to-host-editable-csv-files)

Answer (score 1):

You can force file download of public files on Dropbox by adding `?dl=1` to the public URL. See dropbox.com/en/help/201.

AWS S3 is a popular option too, but it's not straight forward if you are not familiar with AWS already.

Answer (score 1):

2022 answer:

Google sheets now has a built in Publish to web option.
Create your sheet with data then Go to **File** -> **Share** -> **Publish to web**

From the dialog:
Choose the **tab** of the sheet you want to host and the **format** you are publishing to e.g. CSV.
Then click the **Publish** button.
The **URL** is shown on the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

**Direct URLs for Github Files**

After the file has been uploaded to Github, click the filename in the list and you’ll get the file’s URL in the browser’s address. Append `?raw=true` to the URL and you get a downloadable version.

You can use that url in your fetch api like fetch, axios, ajax etc.